# Activities behavior

Tags: android, android-activity

I have four activities A,B,C,D. I am passing an text from activity A to Activity B using bundle and Activity B is displaying it nicely. Then i move from Activity B to Activity C and then Activity D. After that i called Activity B from the Activity D with the help of intent and i seeing no text are there in Activity B.

Please suggest me the way to keep the text there, with some code example.

Comment: What text and where? You need to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use either [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) or [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT).

Without one of these you are creating a new instance of your activity instead of revealing the old one. You can set activity flags on the intent you start from activity D:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

before you call `startActivity`.

Comment: @Matthew: but it work only for one time whenever i changed the text of Activity B and again all the procedure are same then again if i called Activity B from the Activity D i see nothing in Activity B. It Work only one time

Comment: Hmm. Can you describe the sequence of activities you're using?

Comment: A->B->C->D->B. B is having some text view which it is getting from A with the help of bundle and B is displaying it fine but when i moved from D->B i see nothing there in text view.

Comment: I think B is getting restarted when you call `startActivity`. You would need to find some other way for B to know what text to display, or pass it again from D.

Comment: hmm yah right i have an option to do the task but i dont want to do it like this manner e.g with help of bundle i have to pass the data from A-B-C-D and then again D-B.

Comment: Still need help on this topic, if anyone can help me.